# Laravel installation not working as should

Tags: laravel, installation

I am trying to install current version of Laravel on my linux mint system
I am using this command

`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel learn`

the result is

[image: The problem]

> Problem 1
>       - symfony/thanks v1.0.2 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.1 -> no matching package found.
>       - symfony/thanks v1.0.1 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.1 -> no matching package found.
>       - symfony/thanks v1.0.0 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.1 -> no matching package found.
>       - Installation request for symfony/thanks ^1.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/thanks[v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.0.2].
>
> Potential causes:
>    - A typo in the package name
>    - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
>      see https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability for more details.

any one can help thanks in advance .

Comment: Have you tried updating composer? `sudo composer self-update`

Comment: try composer self-update

Comment: [InvalidArgumentException]             
  Command "self-update" is not defined.

Comment: make a try with `php composer.phar self-update`

Comment: You are already using composer version 1.6.2 (stable channel). !!!

Answer (score 0):

**You need to update your version of composer:**

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

**then run this in your project directory:**

```
/usr/local/bin/composer install
```

Comment: the same result
  Problem 1
    - symfony/thanks v1.0.2 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.1 -> no matching package found.
    - symfony/thanks v1.0.1 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.1 -> no matching package found.
    - symfony/thanks v1.0.0 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.1 -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for symfony/thanks ^1.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/thanks[v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.0.2].